# mini-profiler nullreferenceexception

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

When a stored procedure I'm running executes mini-profiler throws a null reference and causes my application to stop.  In this instance the SP doesn't return anything.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
   at MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.AddSqlTiming(SqlTiming stats) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\MiniProfiler.cs:line 274
   at MvcMiniProfiler.SqlTiming..ctor(DbCommand command, ExecuteType type, MiniProfiler profiler) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\SqlTiming.cs:line 137
   at MvcMiniProfiler.SqlProfiler.ExecuteStartImpl(DbCommand command, ExecuteType type) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\SqlProfiler.cs:line 39
   at MvcMiniProfiler.SqlProfilerExtensions.ExecuteStart(SqlProfiler sqlProfiler, DbCommand command, ExecuteType type) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\SqlProfiler.cs:line 93
   at MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.MvcMiniProfiler.Data.IDbProfiler.ExecuteStart(DbCommand profiledDbCommand, ExecuteType executeType) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\MiniProfiler.IDbProfiler.cs:line 14
   at MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 158
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters)
   at NetINFO.NetINFODataContext.usp_SRM_GetPlansByType(Nullable`1 sRM_ID, Nullable`1 sRM_PlanTypeID) in C:\Code\netinfo\NetInfo.Web\App_Data\NetINFO.designer.cs:line 1949
   at NetINFO.NetCMG.SRM.GetSRMPlans(Int32 pPlanType) in C:\Code\netinfo\NetInfo.Web\pages\NetCMG\classes\SRM.cs:line 673
   at NetINFO.NetCMG.SRM.Validate() in C:\Code\netinfo\NetInfo.Web\pages\NetCMG\classes\SRM.cs:line 540
   at NetCMG.Controls.TicketErrorsCtl.ValidateTicket(SRM Ticket) in C:\Code\netinfo\NetInfo.Web\pages\NetCMG\Controls\TicketErrorsCtl.ascx.cs:line 29
   at NetCMG.Controls.TicketErrorsCtl.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Code\netinfo\NetInfo.Web\pages\NetCMG\Controls\TicketErrorsCtl.ascx.cs:line 16
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: @ChaseFlorell I found a solution to my issue.  Not for sure if it is the same as yours or not?

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error now was well. Happens when trying to inject a dependency into a custom RoleProvider.  Something is out of order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution to my question above.  The error was happening on a legacy webforms application that was using sql data source for the grid.  The sql datasource was using the 'ProviderName' property.  Once I removed this property everything started working.

Comment: Thank you, I had another but similar error with SqlDataSource and your answer (removing property ProviderName) is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem: NRE from application start. Exception occures `at MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.AddSqlTiming(SqlTiming stats)`

Problem reason: database call in `Application_AuthenticateRequest()`

Problem solution: `MiniProfiler.Start();` moved to the end of `Application_AuthenticateRequest()` method.